# Customizing a UITableView with Searchbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have a TableView with a search bar. But I want to add another view (lets say a label) in to the TableView (so it scrolls with the tableview) . For an example, if you open iPhones Phone Contacts application, under All Numbers, you can see a lable called "My Number:". Which must be at the same hierarchical level as the searchbar. I tried to add a new label just above the search bar, but storyboards don't allow me to do that.

[image: Document Outline Screenshot for the ViewController]

In here if I drag and drop a UILabel to this hierarchy it either replaces the searchbar at the top , or the label drops inside of the prototype cell. There is no other way of showing searchbar and Label both at once.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate view outside the view controller's view (or inside, it doesn't matter. you can even create this programmatically) and link it to an IBOutlet myCustomView.
Create an IBOutlet searchBar and link your UISearchBar

in viewDidLoad; you can use
    [searchBar addSubView:myCustomView]; 
and add your custom view above the search bar.

you can show/hide (myCustomView.hidden = YES / NO) the custom view or add and remove it from superview whenever you need.

ex.

```
- (IBAction)didTapShowCustomHeaderButton {
    myCustomView.hidden = NO;
}

- (IBAction)didTapHideCustomHeaderButton {
    myCustomView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the below two delegates in the code

```
 - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
    {

     UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30)] autorelease];
      label.text = @"My Label";
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

      return label;   

     }   

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return 30 // this height should be equivalent to the myLabel height u declared in headerView above
        }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. But I need this label to go off the screen with the searchbar when scrolling the table down.

Comment: where exactly do ya want it..i supposed you need it as a part of tableview

Comment: I need to hide the searchbar at runtime and display another UIcontrol when searchbar is hidden. In order to do this I think I have to add that other UIcontrol to the place where  searchbar is exactly positioned (hierarchically)